# Initializing a member of a struct to a function pointer without knowing the returned type

Tags: c, kernel, system-calls

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct xyz_data {
    void *myfa; <------- correct
    void *myfb; <------- incorrect
}
```

and this function definition:

```
asmlinkage ssize_t (*real_sys_read)(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
asmlinkage ssize_t hooked_sys_read(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
```

(as you might be guessing, this will point to the kernel's `__NR_read`).

Saving `hooked_sys_read` to `*myfa;` is as simple as `xyz_data_something->myfa = hooked_sys_read`, but what about `myfb`? I'm not sure `xyz_data_something->myfb = &real_sys_read` will work.

I'm hijacking some syscalls (If you're interested in the project, everything is available in GitHub) and each hijacked syscall will use that struct to call the real syscall it belongs to (which will be accessed via `*myfb`), making use of the returned value.

Keep in mind that each syscall has it's own return type.

Comment: System calls don't return very many different types; they do have varied argument lists. An 'official' way to do it would have a union containing different function pointers for all the different prototypes, and assigning to and using the appropriate member of the union. This is moderately close to how you have to write the function calls using the pointers anyway. Writing generic code in type-safe C gets tricky at this sort of point. You may have to decide which compiler warnings you're going to ignore ... but be very careful because that which you ignore may come back and bite you later.

Answer (score 2):

#### Scenario

```
typedef struct xyz_data {
    void *myfa;
    void *myfb;
} xyz_data;  // Type name assumed — not specified in question

asmlinkage ssize_t (*real_sys_read)(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
asmlinkage ssize_t hooked_sys_read(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);

xyz_data *xyz_data_something = ...;

xyz_data_something->myfa = hooked_sys_read;
xyz_data_something->myfb = &real_sys_read;
```

#### Analysis

What you wrote is not type-safe (so the compiler can't help you much), but you are taking the address of the variable that holds the pointer to the 'real sys read' function, not a copy of that pointer (because of the `&`).  You can apply `&` (and `*`) to function names willy-nilly and they all end up the same:

```
reader->myfa =    &hooked_sys_read;
reader->myfa =     hooked_sys_read;
reader->myfa =    *hooked_sys_read;
reader->myfa =   **hooked_sys_read;
reader->myfa =  ***hooked_sys_read;
reader->myfa = ****hooked_sys_read;
```

You can't do that with pointers to functions.  Note that the compiler cannot even diagnose a 'function pointer assigned to object pointer' problem when you do:

```
xyz_data_something->myfb = &real_sys_read;
```

You are assigning the address of a (function) pointer variable to a `void *`, so you are assigning an object pointer to a void pointer, which is legitimate — but incorrect.

#### Synthesis

You should have one of these two function-type typedefs:

```
typedef ssize_t ReadFunction(unsigned int fd, char __user *data, size_t size);
typedef ssize_t (*ReadPointer)(unsigned int fd, char __user *data, size_t size);
```

Then your structure can be either:

```
typedef struct xyz_data
{
    ReadFunction *myfa;
    ReadFunction *myfb;
} xyz_data;
```

Or:

```
typedef struct xyz_data
{
    ReadPointer myfa;
    ReadPointer myfb;
} xyz_data;
```

Given a structure pointer:

```
xyz_data *reader = ...;
```

The following assignments will compile cleanly and work correctly (for both structure types):

```
reader->myfa = hooked_sys_read;
reader->myfb = real_sys_read;
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#define asmlinkage
#define __user

asmlinkage ssize_t (*real_sys_read)(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
asmlinkage ssize_t hooked_sys_read(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);

typedef ssize_t (*ReadPointer)(unsigned int fd, char __user *data, size_t size);

typedef struct xyz_data
{
    ReadPointer myfa;
    ReadPointer myfb;
} xyz_data;

extern xyz_data getter(void);

xyz_data getter(void)
{
    xyz_data data;
    xyz_data *reader = &data;

    reader->myfa = hooked_sys_read;
    reader->myfb = real_sys_read;
//  The next line fails to compile: assignment from incompatible pointer type
//  reader->myfb = &real_sys_read;

    reader->myfa =    &hooked_sys_read;
    reader->myfa =     hooked_sys_read;
    reader->myfa =    *hooked_sys_read;
    reader->myfa =   **hooked_sys_read;
    reader->myfa =  ***hooked_sys_read;
    reader->myfa = ****hooked_sys_read;
    return *reader;
}
```

It compiles cleanly.  It isn't good code, though — the repeated assignments alone are enough to make it bad.

Comment: Hmmm... So I should access both functions (the hooked one and the real one) via that getter. How about storing a pointer to that getter? Let's say I'll hook read, write, open and close syscalls. All those 4 syscalls will contain their information in a structure (so then I could iterate over all the structs and hook/unhook each syscall). Will something like ```typedef struct hooks { void *pointer_getter; }``` work?

Comment: No; the `getter()` function is merely the simplest dressing I could come up with that would compile; you should not use it directly.  It does illustrate the point about the syntax allowed with function pointers, which is nigh-on unbelievable until you've seen it (and that was the primary purpose).  I think you should be use strict types in the typedefs for the function pointers (but I may be being anal retentive about that).  I definitely think that using `void *` is bad — for type safety if nothing else.  There are occasions when `void *` is necessary; this isn't one of them.

Comment: Then that won't work for me (imho). I need a way to store, in the same struct, pointers to different syscalls. Maybe with some macro magic (stringify-ing var names and so on)

Comment: Another contributor of the project got it :)  https://github.com/alexandernst/procmon/commit/1d3e33cb80d97c424b147b035c0fa7ee1cf502d9

Answer (score 1):

You should not be assigning a function pointer to a void pointer.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5579907/1351983.

Comment: How could I store a function pointer (of whatever type) in a single type of data and then cast it back?

Comment: If you know the return type and parameters of the function you will be pointing to, include them in the pointer declaration. I can't think of a good reason for calling functions where these are different through the same function pointer.

Comment: @alexandernst As it says in the answer you're linked to "A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again". So just replace your void pointers with any function pointer type you fancy, and you can then do what you want.

Comment: POSIX requires that function pointers and data pointers are the same size (if only because of dynamic loading and [`dlopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html) and
[`dlsym()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html)).  Standard C doesn't, but the Unix (Linux) kernel is hardly pure C.  So, theoretically, you're correct; in practice, you're observation is largely immaterial on the grounds given.